# Minimum Path to Travel (N-1) 1D Points

Tags: algorithm

In order to travel to all (N-1) points, one would usually use a MST / Travelling Sales Man problem, but I found an equation that needs explanation for calculating such in O(1) for 1D points.

```
min( min(abs(b[0]-a) + b[n-2]-b[0], abs(b[n-2]-a) + b[n-2]-b[0]), min( abs(b[1]-a) + b[n-1]-b[1], abs(b[n-1]-a) + b[n-1] - b[1]))
```

Where `b[]` is the array of the given points and `a` is the starting location.
The source of the problem and the equation are from Codeforces:

http://codeforces.com/contest/709/status/B

I would appreciate any help explaining this mathematical maneuver.

Comment: You need to be more clear about what this equation is supposed to do and what you want to learn about it.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far. You should include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looking at the [problem definition](http://codeforces.com/contest/709/problem/B), it does not mentions that the input of the points are sorted in some order.
The way you gave is possible only if you first **sort** the input points, and then yes, finding the minimum path is O(1) by calculating this equation. Though, total runtime complexity will be O(nlogn).

**Explanation of the equation:**
Think of it as all the points are in a row (after sorting). You are given a starting point and you need to visit `n-1` points, meaning that you need to visit all points except for only one. From this we know that minimum path will be one of the two:

1. All points except for the first one
2. All points except for the last one

The equation you gave calculates exactly that.

Comment: Thank you, but please correct me if I'm wrong, considering this cleaner piece of code;
[link](http://codeforces.com/contest/709/status/B#). There're four cases, since the minus indices mean starting from the tail of the sorted array.

Comment: I don't exactly get what you mean. Why do you have negative indices? This equation works for every `n >= 2`.

Comment: Hey @A.Sarid, The negative indices are a way to tell Ruby or Python to get start from the tail of the array. That's the last element, the second to last, .. etc.
Thank you for your reply & your help.